# Cheese webcam app doesn't see webcam in 64-bit ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, webcam, cheese

When I run the [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) app it shows nothing (see below) instead of picture from my webcam.

[image: cheese app screenshot]

However `guvcview` (a webcam viewer app) recognizes my webcam and I see the picture from it.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: to run web cheese camera shows nothing

Comment: Web cheese? What?

Comment: Web cheese does not run.
black screen

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the request for clarification:  What is 'web cheese'?  Do you have a link to it?  Did it work before?

Comment: Cheese webcam application.
Ubuntu comes installed with 16.
It does not work, black screen.

Comment: @fram I am familiar with Cheese, and I use it in 64 bit Ubuntu, but what is `web cheese`? Please add a screenshot, that might help to understand better.

Comment: attach image and link to the original question

Comment: should be the other way around, but... try from command line `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so cheese` (you need the package libv4l-0:amd64). Fixes a similar problem in chrome.

Comment: Rmano thanks for answering.
I have fear run $ LD_PRELOAD = ........
who does that?

Comment: run LD_PRELOAD = / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / libv4l / v4l2convert.so cheese.
The result is the same. webcam cheese black screen.
libv4l-0 already in their most recent version.

Comment: Clarified duplicate.
one is in ubuntu 14.4lts and another is is ubuntu 16.04 lts.
some people tell me that web cheese works in ubuntu 14 lst.
but I do not know why.
I am sorry.